# How to access the method which is available in the service collection to perform unit tests

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, service

I would like to access the finder object inside the unit test class in order to perform test cases, but I am pretty new to the service collections and async programming please help me out with some leads or solution.

```
// startup class

 public static class Startup
    {
        public static IServiceCollection Configure(IServiceCollection services = null)
        {
            services = services ?? new ServiceCollection();

            services.AddSingleton<ILongestRisingSequenceFinder, LongestRisingSequenceFinder>();

            return services;
        }
    }
```

// Inside Unit test class we should be able to get the method data to check the test cases

```
public class UnitTests
        {
            [Theory]
            [InlineData(new [] {4,3,5,8,5,0,0,-3}, new [] {3,5,8})]
            public async Task CanFind(IEnumerable<int> data, IEnumerable<int> expected)
            {
                IEnumerable<int> actual = null;
    
                // TODO: create the finder instance and get the actual result
    
                actual.Should().Equal(expected);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `var bob = new LongestRisingSequenceFinder();` _Do not be tempted to resolve them from the `IServiceCollection`._

Comment: this ^^^ you are unit testing `LongestRisingSequenceFinder` not `ILongestRisingSequenceFinder` or `ServiceProvider`

Comment: I am new to this unit testing stuff, thanks for guiding me towards the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commenters have noted, you are testing the class `LongestRisingSequenceFinder`. Good unit tests dispense with other concerns, and test one thing. Instead, skip service resolution, which is a completely separate concern.

Your test should look like

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(new [] {4,3,5,8,5,0,0,-3}, new [] {3,5,8})]
public async Task CanFind(IEnumerable<int> data, IEnumerable<int> expected)
{
    var finder = new LongestRisingSequenceFinder();

    // a guess on usage...
    var actual = finder.MethodOfFinder(...);
    
    actual.Should().Equal(expected);
}
```

If you're truly wanting to test service resolution with a call to the method, this is an integration test. A test like that is going to require constructing a test server, doing all the dependency injection, etc. *in the context of the server*.

Simply creating an artificial container as your code shows and then calling the method adds no value to testing. Think about it this way; your code was creating a container with 1 entry for the sole purpose of getting an entry. That's a really complicated way to instead just do `new` in your test, so adds no value.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, It helped a lot @kit